# Solution to find holidays in persian calendar (shamsi)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I need to know Persian calendar holidays in react
and I don't want to use paid APIs.
Is there any way to get Persian (shamsi) holidays for **free **?

I need to know holidays with it's description.

```json
{
1402:[
    {
      date: "1402/1/2",
      description: "عیدنوروز",
    },
    ...
]
}
```

Help me to find a free API or free solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this script for free at time.ir website to have static holidays in specific years
[detect Persian holidays script](https://gist.github.com/hosseinmasoomi/0d5f873ec54e5538d3f46264c82d4126)

Comment: its was real :)